# Check if a value exists in the json record?

Tags: python, json

I have a json file with the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "AAAA": {
      "action": "bypass"
    }
  },
  {
    "BBBB": {
      "action": "bypass"
    }
  }
]
```

I need to check if some values exist in json, i try:

```
print("AAAA" in data)
```

But I get result "False". How can I check if a value exists in the json record?

Comment: Please add your code that shows how you are getting the file contents into the variable `data`.

Comment: `"AAAA"` in data[0] will return `True`. So, just iterate over the elements of the list and check if each dict has that value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over each item in the array and check if your specific search key exists in the item's keys. So,

```
def check_value_in_data(data, search_value):
    for item in data:
        if search_value in item.keys():
            return True
    return False
```

should return True/False if the value exists.